# rospack error: package 'roscpp' not found

Tags: rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new to ROS and Linux, I am following tutorial on ROS installation, when i run the `rospack find roscpp`
I get the following respond `[rospack] Error: package 'roscpp' not found` not sure why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264077/rospack--error:-package-%27roscpp%27-not-found/) by [UaeZombie](https://answers.ros.org/users/30802/uaezombie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure, when following the install tutorial, you executed the command

```
echo "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```

This sets up your shell to always add the correct ROS variables to the Linux environment. You should then be able to use `rospack find roscpp` correctly. If not, check the output of `printenv | grep ROS` includes the lines:

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/share
```

If the output is correct, but `rospack find` isn't working, we have another problem.

---

Originally posted by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) with karma: 885 on 2017-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [UaeZombie](https://answers.ros.org/users/30802/uaezombie/) on 2017-06-19**:
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/uaefame/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
still not working

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-06-19**:
What version of Linux do you have? Fuerte is 5 years old now and I highly recommend installing something more recent. Preferably Kinetic, but Indigo at least.

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-06-19**:
Anyway, your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH doesn't contain the path to the actual ros install. Type `echo "source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc` and restart your terminal.